# TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null angular2 typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I store a part of my HTML code in database. 
When I need to open my objects (to get list of objects) I need to initialize my view with the first object `list[0].content`.

So I get a tag div by where I want to put my html coming from database

```
elemet:HTMLElement;
this.element = document.getElementById("content");
getList(){
 this._service.getList()
            .subscribe(
                data => {
                    this.list = data;
                    this.element.innerHTML = this.list[0].content;
                    }
                },
                error => alert(error),
                () => {
                    console.log("finished");
                }
            );
}
```

So I get this error I cant set my view.

And I call this method in the constructor

(in javascript it exist window.onload ...)

Comment: What's the output of `console.log(this.element)` just before ` this.element.innerHTML = this.list[0].content;`?

Comment: I'd bind to a variable in the template to avoid directly manipulating the DOM.

Comment: [object HTMLDivElement] this is the output

in fact I have in my view a list of my object I can select anyone to get the content in my div .
in the load page I get my Div empty but when i select the object i get correctly my view 

so i think my probleme is in load page

Comment: how can I bind a variable can you give me an example , thanks.

Comment: when I put a variable like this 
<div  [innerHTML]="obj.content">

 </div>
the content display and disappear quickly